# making buttons change size along when zoom

Tags: objective-c, uiview, uiscrollview, uibutton

I have a UIScrollView, with a UIImageView and UIButton inside of it.

[image]

I was reading in the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1580100/uibuttons-over-a-uiimageview-zooming) that if I have a single view that contains all of my zoomable content, then I should be fine.  The problem is that the button doesn't zoom when the image does.

I thought that what I have would work, since the Scroll View is the zoomable view.

Do I need to create another UIView and put everything in there (and keep the same hierarchy?) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up fixing this by declaring the button in code, and added a UView into the hiearchy.  The uiview is a subview of the scroll view, and the imageview is a subview of the uiview.  I then added the buttons to the uiview.

```
UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
...
[view addSubview:button];
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked your Springs and Struts?  Look in the size inspector under "autosizing".  Those little red lines.. if that doesn't make sense, search for 'auto layout'.

Comment: everything seems to be in order there, I have all of the red lines enabled so that in the example the red box expands with the bigger box